# MYSQL - SUM values of last 10 days

Tags: mysql, date, if-statement, sum, case

I have this table in mysql:

```
|   player1   |  player2 |    date    |   fs_1   |   fs_2   |
    Jack         Tom       2015-03-02       10         2
    Mark        Riddley    2015-05-02       3          1 
     ...
```

I need to know how many aces (fs_1) player 1 have done BEFORE the match reported in date_g (10 days before for example).

This is what i tried without success:

**OPTION 1**

```
    SELECT 
    players_atp.name_p AS 'PLAYER 1',
    P.name_p AS 'PLAYER 2',
    DATE(date_g) AS 'DATE',
    result_g AS 'RESULT',
    FS_1,
    FS_2,
    SUM(IF(date_sub(date_g, interval 10 day)< date_g, FS_1, 0)) AS 'last 10 days'
FROM
    stat_atp stat_atp
        JOIN
    backup3.players_atp ON ID1 = id_P
        JOIN
    backup3.players_atp P ON P.id_p = id2
        JOIN
    backup3.games_atp ON id1_g = id1 AND id2_g = id2
        AND id_t_g = id_t
        AND id_r_g = id_r
WHERE
    date_g > '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY ID1;
```

**OPTION 2**

```
SELECT 
    players_atp.name_p AS 'PLAYER 1',
    P.name_p AS 'PLAYER 2',
    DATE(date_g) AS 'DATE',
    result_g AS 'RESULT',
    FS_1,
    FS_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_g between date_g and date_sub(date_g, interval 10 day) then fs_1 else 0 end) AS 'last 10 days'
FROM
    stat_atp stat_atp
        JOIN
    backup3.players_atp ON ID1 = id_P
        JOIN
    backup3.players_atp P ON P.id_p = id2
        JOIN
    backup3.games_atp ON id1_g = id1 AND id2_g = id2
        AND id_t_g = id_t
        AND id_r_g = id_r
WHERE
    date_g > '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY ID1;
```

---

I have edited the code, now is more easy to read and understand.

```
 SELECT 
     id1 AS 'PLAYER 1',
     id2 AS 'PLAYER 2',
     DATE(date_g) AS 'DATE',
     result_g AS 'RESULT',
     FS_1,
     FS_2,
     SUM(CASE
         WHEN date_g BETWEEN date_g AND DATE_SUB(date_g, INTERVAL 10 DAY) THEN fs_1
     END) AS 'last 20 days' FROM
     stat_atp stat_atp
         JOIN
     backup3.games_atp ON id1_g = id1 AND id2_g = id2
         AND id_t_g = id_t
         AND id_r_g = id_r GROUP BY ID1;
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you give us the other tables ? It would be more understandable, especially because you are using an aggregation for your statistics (GROUP BY). However, you should not use condition in the projection part of your query (SELECT). It's more suitable in the restriction part (WHERE).

Comment: There's scope for further normalisation here

Comment: I have update the code. check if it is more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help you:

```
SELECT 
    id1,
    SUM(fs_1)
FROM 
     stat_atp
WHERE
     date_g <= DATE_SUB('2015-03-02', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND date_g >= DATE_SUB('2015-03-02', INTERVAL 10 DAY)
AND
    id1='Jack'
GROUP BY id1;
```

Remember that RDBMS are used to construct rigorous data sets that are linked between each others by clear ids (*keys* when talking about SQL). It's easier to respect the three first **normal forms**. That's why you should use keys to identify your match itself. By this way you could use subqueries (subsets) to achieve your goal.

Then, keep in mind that SQL is **STRUCTURED**. It's its force and weakness cause you won't be able to use it as a Turing complete programming langage with loops and conditions. But in any situation you will be able to find the same structure for a query. However you can interact with a SQL query result with another langage and use loops and condition on the result set itself. That's up to you.

Anyway, you may want to read about the MySQL GROUP BY clause which is different from the ISO SQL form : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thanx a lot.
I edited the code with your implementation and it works but not like I would. I'll try with mathlab, after your suggestion, to improve the query.

Comment: You're welcome ! Maybe you could up vote this answer if it has help you.